# Is $x_{n+1}=\cos x_n$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $x\in \Bbb R$ ; then is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ where $a_1=x$; $a_{n+1}=\cos (a_n)$ convergent?

Obviously $|a_n|\le1$  and hence $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Also $f(x)=\cos x$ is decreasing for $x>0$.

But here $x\in \Bbb R$ .How to proceed here?Please help.

Comment: Fixed point theorems?  Google?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html

Comment: Hint : Use the Banach-fixpoint-theorem

Comment: This has been asked before, probably à propos the similar recursion based on the sine since I remember having explained the differences between these two situations...

Answer (score 4):

Note that since $|a_n| \le 1$ we have $a_n \in [0,1]$ since $\cos$
is positive on $[-1,1]$.

Since $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ we see that $a_n \ge \cos 1 >0$ for all $n \ge 2$.

In particular, $a_n \in [\cos 1, 1]$ for $n \ge 2$ and we have
$|\cos'x| \le \sin 1 < 1$ for $x \in [\cos 1, 1]$ and so
$\cos$ is a contraction map on $[\cos 1, 1]$. Hence $a_n$ converges
to the unique fixed point.

Comment: I don't get one thing.Take $x=(\pi+\frac{\pi}{3})$;then $\cos x=\frac{-1}{2}$;Why do you say that $a_n\in [0,1]$??

Comment: I meant for $n \ge 2$. As you noted, $|a_n | \le 1$ for $n \ge 2$ (the first value is arbitrary), but there after $|a_n| \le1$. If $|x| \le 1$, then $\cos x \ge \cos 1$Also, i

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\{a_n\} $ is an infinite subset of $[-1,1] $. Therefore it has a convergent subsequence since $[-1,1]$ is compact. Now check that "is the subsequences converge to a unique point or not"!