# $a_1 =π/4$, $a_{n+1}= \cos(a_n)$. Prove that $\lim(a_n) =c$ when $c =\cos(c)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have been struggling for too long,
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this one ?
$a_1 =π/4\:$ and $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$

Prove that $$\lim_{a_n \to \infty} =c\;\text{ when } \; c = \cos(c)$$

Comment: You have a recurrent sequence, it should be pretty easy to apply the convergence theorem for such sequences

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2164009/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227317/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2382210/42969

Answer (score 0):

If you have
$$a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$$ **If** the limit $L$ exists, it is, by definition, the solution of
$$L=\cos(L)$$ and this is [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html).

The value of $a_1$ has nothing to do.

So, you need to prove the convergence of the series.